# Is there a way to give a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline raw text and a list of tokens as input?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pipeline, tokenize, arabic

I'm doing some natural language processing with Arabic. Since I'm working with a couple different NLP tools in tandem, I want to be able to be able to give raw text to a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline, but provide my own list of tokens rather than having it do the tokenization. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to merge your tokens with whitespace and then use the `-tokenize.whitespace` option.

So for instance if I had the raw text: `This is a sentence.`, and I tokenize it into `("This", "is", "a", "sentence", ".")` I would merge that back into a string `"This is a sentence ."` and use the `tokenize.whitespace` option which will just split on whitespace.

Comment: Makes sense, but I have a concern. I need this other tool to do some extensive morphological analysis and base phrase chunking that Stanford does not provide, so I need to use its tokenization scheme. However, one of the important things I need Stanford to do is give me the beginning and ending indices of each word as they stand in the original text--so I need an exact alignment between the list of tokens each tool uses. Merging my tokens with white space can do that but it will offset the indices for each word.